# Issue when installing bundles in Fuse using Ops4j Pax URL mvn

Tags: maven, installation, fuse, apache-servicemix

I am using Fuse 6.10 from Redhat. I also using archiva to host all bundle
Now, i have a problem:
In Fuse terminal, if we use bellow command, then it works fine:

```
install -s http://xxxx/archiva/repositories/snapshots/com/aaa/bbb/Order/1.0/Order-1.0.jar
```

But if we use the mvn url then the install does not work

```
install -s mvn:com.aaa.bbb/Order/1.0
```

The error is : Unable to install bundle mvn:com.aaa.bbb/Order/1.0

```
We can see that pax url mvn is active
[   1] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [    5] OPS4J Pax Url - mvn: (1.3.7)
```

Assume that all url is correct, Do you know if we need to add anything?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your own repo correctly?
Make sure that you adapt the following section in your org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg file found in the etc folder:

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories= \
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2@id=central, \
https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapachekaraf-1027@id=stage, \
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/m2-repo@id=servicemix, \
http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release@id=springsource.release, \
http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external@id=springsource.external, \
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/@id=sonatype, \
https://your.own.archiva.server.here/repo
```

Comment: yes, i did it. org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg file is working on my local but it does not work on linux server instance. i was though about the firewall between linux server and archiva server. But if i use http://archiva../...jar then it works. So i can eleminate the network connection issue.

Comment: Well if it works in one box (your local one) but doesn't in the other, it's surely a network/firewall issue and not related to Karaf or Pax URL at this point.